# Any usefull setups, which have the same IP range on multiple interfaces?

Tags: networking

I'm writing a small network scanner utility for use on a mobile computer. Therefore I have to consider almost every possible combination of networks. Although I would never advise this, but is it possible to have the same IP range on multiple interfaces? For example 192.168.0.1/24 on eth0 and eth1. Could there be any setup, where this makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can't have the same IP address on multiple interfaces, on the same host or different ones (except for some NIC teaming setups).

A host may have multiple IP addresses on the same subnet though, on multiple interfaces or just a single one. Use cases include running multiple services each bound to a dedicated IP address, load balancing/ECMP or failover scenarios.